# LINQ-to-SQL IN/Contains() for Nullable<T>

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, nullable

I want to generate this SQL statement in LINQ:

```
select * from Foo where Value in ( 1, 2, 3 )
```

The tricky bit seems to be that Value is a column that allows nulls.

The equivalent LINQ code would seem to be:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> foos = MyDataContext.Foos;
IEnumerable<int> values = GetMyValues();
var myFoos = from foo in foos
             where values.Contains(foo.Value)
             select foo;
```

This, of course, doesn't compile, since `foo.Value` is an `int?` and `values` is typed to `int`.

I've tried this:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> foos = MyDataContext.Foos;
IEnumerable<int> values = GetMyValues();
IEnumerable<int?> nullables = values.Select( value => new Nullable<int>(value));
var myFoos = from foo in foos
             where nullables.Contains(foo.Value)
             select foo;
```

...and this:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> foos = MyDataContext.Foos;
IEnumerable<int> values = GetMyValues();
var myFoos = from foo in foos
             where values.Contains(foo.Value.Value)
             select foo;
```

Both of these versions give me the results I expect, but they do not generate the SQL I want. It appears that they're generating full-table results and then doing the Contains() filtering in-memory (ie: in plain LINQ, without -to-SQL); there's no `IN` clause in the DataContext log.

Is there a way to generate a SQL IN for Nullable types?

## NOTE

As it turns out, the problem I was having didn't have anything to do Contains or Nullable, and so the phrasing of my question is largely irrelevant. See @Nick Craver's accepted answer for details.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This should work for your example:

```
IEnumerable<int> values = GetMyValues();
var myFoos = from foo in MyDataContext.Foos;
             where values.Contains(foo.Value.Value)
             select foo;
```

Casting as an `IEnumerable<T>` from the start means execution will be outside of SQL, instead call the `IQueryable<Foo>` directly.  If you cast as `IEnumerable` and use it in a query, it gets all `MyDataContext.Foos` then uses that iterator and executes the rest of the query in C# instead of in SQL.

If you want to run in SQL, don't cast as `IEnumerable` anywhere along the way.  The effect is the same as using `MyDataContext.Foos.AsEnumerable()` in the query.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize that casting the references made a difference (undoubtedly due to the use of specifically-typed extension methods). That's unfortunate from a OOP point of view. However, it did solve my problem. Thanks!